# read Access Control List of a file in python

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, acl

Is there a canonical way to read the access control list of a file in python under linux/OSX ?
In the `os` module, I use the `os.stat` function to access properties of a file, but I did not find how to read the access control list. And `os.chmod` doesn't seem to be able to change ACL either...

Comment: To clarify... do you mean the ACL for a file, or the the standard unix-style permissions for a file...

Comment: There's `pylibacl`, but I've not used it: http://pylibacl.k1024.org/

Comment: @NPE: I've seen blog posts talking about how it doesn't work on OS X, and it appears to be Python 2.x only.

Comment: @JonClements for standard permissions, there is no problem, it's easily accessible through `os.stat`.

Comment: @Xoff that's fine... just wanted to make sure "access control list" wasn't being used in some general sense... the "`os.chmod` doesn't seem to be able to change ACL either" had me wondering...

Comment: Yep, I'm on OSX, that's why... :) I did not remember there was getfacl/setfacl on standard unix.